# Who could this be?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Who am I talking about?

> My first is unpredictable, if you add some from the middle 
> My second is one, but a short line splits it apart 
> The first part is a common word, if you come from the Middle 
> The last is worthy, coming from the bottom guard

Just a warning, I've been extra obscure about this one, because almost everyone here has seen the answer.

Comment: "My second is one, but a short line splits it apart" = ome?

Comment: @randal'thor: Nope.

Comment: @randal'thor - I'm not good with riddles.  I suspect that you are the best per'son to solve this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Len has [given me an idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17090/who-could-this-be?noredirect=1#comment53518_17090)...

> [Are you *me*?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20515421#20515421)

*My first is unpredictable, if you add some from the middle*

> My first is *rand*; adding the middle half (om) of "some" gives random - a synonym of unpredictable.

*My second is one, but a short line splits it apart*

> My second is *al'thor*: one word, with an apostrophe (short line) splitting it apart.

*The first part is a common word, if you come from the Middle*

> The first part of al'thor is *al*, which is the translation into Arabic (a common language in the Middle East) of the commonest word in English. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_definite_article).

*The last is worthy, coming from the bottom guard*

> The last part is *thor*; Thor comes from Asgard (which is a homophone of arse guard, which is a synonym of bottom guard), and he's the only one 'worthy' to lift Mjolnir in the Marvel films.

*almost everyone here has seen the answer.*

> I'm very active on Puzzling.SE!

I'm very flattered by this riddle - thanks CodeNewbie for the compliment! :-D

Comment: @Len is right about how I made random.

Comment: Only your second clue is deciphered correctly. In the third, the 'Middle' (with a capital M for emphasis) was supposed to signify the Middle East. For the last line, think of what word is often called the bottom.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I'm very flattered that you wrote a riddle about me! :-D Middle East was my first thought on line 3, but I wasn't sure how to make it fit ... anything to do with [this](http://www.rand.org/international/cmepp.html)? And in line 4, is it "bottom" as in butt or as in base?

Comment: You know the answer to clue 3 is 'al'. Think of what language is spoken in the Middle East and try to translate a very common word into that language. Similarly for clue 4, you know the answer. Butt is the right inference, but I'm thinking of a cuss word there. (Just replace the cuss word in that line and it should make sense.) And making this riddle is just my way of doffing the hat to a valuable member of our community.

Comment: The worthy, who comes from Ass-guard (*spelled wrong, but sounds right). Don't you watch Marvel movies?

Comment: "The last is worthy" the last bit of "al'thor" is thor, or Thor, the God of lightning, according to Norse mythology. And Thor is most certainly "worthy".

Comment: @CodeNewbie Good one! Ass-guard and Asgard. Nice wordplay!

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yep - I was editing while you were writing your comment! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor: I see you're still confused about the worthy bit. The whole plot of the first Thor movie revolved around Thor proving himself to be worthy enough to wield Mjolnir. And even the massively strong Hulk cannot lift Mjolnir because he isn't worthy of it.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Nope, I've never seen Marvel films, but I do know Norse mythology!