# You may find me... puzzling

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am within my rights to stay silent.
>   I am abandoned in the middle.
>   I am held in by spirit.
>   I am African capital.

Who or what am I?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Added "riddle", thanks. (How did I miss that?) "Geography" might just be misleading here so I've left it out on purpose.

Comment: both of us missed that too in the previous ones. it was rand who helped us add it... :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who could this be?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17090/5373) :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought you were jafe, but looks like you might be

> [Rand](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) instead!

I am within my rights to stay silent.

> The [Mi**rand**a rights](http://www.mirandawarning.org/whatareyourmirandarights.html) include the right to remain silent

I am abandoned in the middle.

> St**rand**ed

I am held in by spirit.

> B**rand**y

I am African capital.

> [Rand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_rand) is the official currency, or "capital" of South Africa.

Comment: Everything's correct!